# How do i bound the inheritance chain?

Tags: rust

I want to write a func that could cast to the up  inheritance chain.
It's intend for ,windows COM interface, so I could get a ptr,to the upper,

```
//something like this..

impl Deref<Target = B> for A{}
impl Deref<Target = C> for B{}
fn foo<U>(a: A) where A:Deref<Target = U> {
    //this could't work,it's just for B,can't for C
}
```

How should i write bound for this case?

Comment: `Deref` is not inheritance, it's for smart pointers. Inheritance in Rust usually refers to `trait A: B {}` (although strictly speaking, it's not inheritance but bounds).

Comment: Also, this sounds like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Why can't you change the caller to dereference (`&*`)?

Comment: Could you explain the intention of `foo` a bit more? What is it supposed to do?
The reason you can't call foo(c) with a C instance is because C doesn't implement Deref. But you can implement it, can't you?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman 
thanks for help!  I learned that had make mistake!

Comment: @battlmonstr
I don't know why I lost my mind at that time.
i impl a method in ComPtr<T>(NollNull<T>),`pub fn up_raw<U>(&self) -> *mut U where T<T: Deref<Target = U>,  U: Interface,`
there is common to called in func by their up pointer, this is enough.
I almost impossible to use something like "Trait C" to call this,for winapi...
I have lerand...Thank you for your help and Chayim Friedman

Comment: > there is common to called in func **with** their up pointer.
my english is poor,,and found write wrong above.